# How to approximate a function to make it differentiable?

Tags: functions, derivatives, optimization, numerical-methods

> I was reading a paper which made the median function
> $$ \mathcal{M} = \arg\min_c\sum_{j=1}^N\|x_j-c\|_p,$$
> differentiable by replacing arg min with a softmax to form
> a weighted average, i.e. $ \mathcal{M} \approx \mathbf{s}^T\mathbf{X},$
> where the softmax function is
> $$ s_i = \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{T}||x_j-x_i||}}{\sum_{q=1}^ne^{-\frac{1}{T}||x_j-x_q||}}$$

Softmax was used so that the weights are between $0$ and $1$, we could easily put it through other functions too. But, are there any other different methods to approximate this function (and similar ones) to make them differentiable?

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with differential forms. Please don't use tags whose meaning you do not know.

Answer (score 0):

There are a near infinite number of ways to approximate it. In the context of optimization, one common technique would be to optimize the parameters at a sequence of fixed temperature parameters $T$ (using your softmax formulation), gradually increasing $T\rightarrow\infty$. In other words, optimize first at $T=10$ then $T=100$, etc. all the while using the latest optimization weights $x_i$ from the previous optimization.

This has the effect of making the softmax converge to the maximum value, while also optimizing over a differentiable function.